# Probe at low current load to measure voltage using oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope

I have a circuit with a load where i'm measuring the current across the load with an ammeter and the typical current consumption of the load is typically within 10uA range.

When I connect my oscilloscope probe at the load in parallel to check the voltage response, the current consumption load is hitting my the current clamp (50uA) as set in my ammeter and everything back to normal once i disconnect my voltage probe from the load.

Can anyone please explain why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd need to show the connections.  Perhaps the ground clip is to blame?   A decent scope should be 1 Megaohm impedance, but cheap alternatives might be less.  Using a 10x probe could help.

Comment: 1.  You measure current **through** a load.  2.  Consider where you placed the ground clip of the oscilloscope.